# function using dictionary as argument

Tags: python, function, dictionary, arguments

I have created a dictionary with values for Velocity, temperature and altitude:

```
mach_dict = dict(velocity=[], altitude=[], temperature=[])
```

Which I use to store values for a flying plain at climb, cruise and descent segments.

```
mach_dict = {'velocity': [0, 300, 495, 500, 300], 'altitude': [288.15, 288.15, 288.15, 288.15, 288.15], 'temperature': [0, 0, 50, 50, 50]}
```

I need to create a function (def) that returns a dictionary that stores the mach number for every segment.

To estimate `Mach` I use the formula:

```
Mach = velocity / sqrt(1.4 * 286 * (Temperature - altitude * 0.05))
```

Can anybody help on that?

Comment: Can you clarify what the output should look like?

Comment: You mean you need to calculate mach for each index into the 3 lists?

Comment: sqrt is negative in some cases! temperature=0 => sqrt (negative) => error.

Answer (score 0):

You can `zip` the list values in the dictionary and compute the new key `mach_number` using a *list comprehension*:

```
import math

def compute_mach(velocity, altitude, temperature):
    return velocity/math.sqrt(1.4*286*(temperature-altitude*0.05))

mach_dict['mach_number'] = [compute_mach(v, a, t)  for v, a, t in zip(mach_dict['velocity'], 
                                                                      mach_dict['altitude'], 
                                                                      mach_dict['temperature'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd zip together the 3 lists to produce `velocity, altitude, temperature` tuples:

```
mach_dict['mach'] = mach_per_section = []
for vel, alt, temp in zip(
        mach_dict['velocity'], mach_dict['altitude'], mach_dict['temperature']):
    mach = vel / sqrt(1.4 * 286 * (temp - alt * 0.05))
    mach_per_section.append(mach)
```

Unfortunately, your inputs lead to a `ValueError: math domain error` because for some you'd get a negative value for `1.4 * 286 * (temp - alt * 0.05)`.

Comment: You could use `cmath.sqrt` -- Mach numbers can be `complex`, right?  :-P

Comment: @mgilson: that 'works' in that it produces `[0j, -3.949843661534238j, (4.146473724484641+0j), (4.188357297459233+0j), (2.51301437847554+0j)]`...

Comment: I think that the problem is actually `0` temperature -- Getting to absolute 0 is pretty tricky to pull off...

Comment: Yeah, if these are not in Kelvin but in Celcius or Farenheit then some conversion is due.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, this is modifying the passed in dictionary, and the `return` is unnecessary.

```
from math import sqrt

def func(d):
    machs = []
    for v, a, t in zip(d['velocity', d['altitude'], d['temperature']):
        mach = v / sqrt(1.4 * 286 * (t - a * 0.05))
        machs.append(mach)
    d['mach'] = machs
    return d
```

Answer (score 0):

And you can use pandas and numpy to do that as well

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



def compute(mach_dict):
   df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mach_dict)
   r = df.velocity / np.sqrt(1.4 * 286 * (df.temperature - df.altitude * 0.05))
   return list(r)

mach_dict={'velocity':[0, 300, 495, 500, 300],'altitude':[288.15, 288.15, 288.15, 288.15, 288.15],'temperature':[0, 0, 50, 50, 50]}
print(compute(mach_dict))
```

This will handle the -ve case that it would give you NaN